# Is there anyway to add CSS on particular text in a tag using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

So i have this, i just want to set font-size of the R with Different Color. i have tried Pseudo elements and classes, i couldn't find any solution.

```css
.normal-text p{font-size:18px;color:red; text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="normal-text">
<p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"font-size of the R"* ... which R?

Comment: Question Edited Please check again.

Comment: Making a single letter in a text a different color with CSS pseudo elements is effectively impossible. You can try to arrange an `::after` element precisely so that it covers the `r`, but the alignment will be off as soon as screen resolution, font, and zoom level change. There is no way you will always get the red `r` *exactly* over the black one.

Comment: At the moment only the `::first-letter` pseudo-element in CSS is well supported for this purpose. Regarding your question, unfortunately it addresses only the first letter of an element.

Comment: Yeah i have tried ::first-letter pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no selector in css for mid range letter. Perhaps you could try javascript solution for this.

Steps:

1. split the string
2. select the index
3. add `<span>` and join the array
4. update the transformed value to the original element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p span {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="og">Lorem</p>

<script>
let str = document.getElementById("og").innerHTML;
const myArr = str.split("");
myArr[2] = '<span>'+myArr[2]+'</span>';
let myString = myArr.join();
myString = myString.replaceAll(',', '');
document.getElementById("og").innerHTML = myString;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `::after` to position another color `r` over the actual one... like this:

```css
.normal-text {
  text-align:center;
}
.normal-text p {
  font-size:18px;
  color:red;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  }
.normal-text p:after {
  content:'r';
  color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:20px;
  display:block;
  width:6px;
  height:21px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal-text">
<p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Notice I did add a white background color and make it a `block` element to avoid inconsistences when zooming in and out your browser.

But still far from perfect. Community has been asking for a `::nth-letter()` as a `CSS` property since 2012 with no success.

Comment: Appreciate with your answer, but also i need to change font size larger of the R.

Comment: Look for a javascript option then. Not possible with just CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the letter `r` inside a span tag and give that a different color:

```
<p>Lo<span class="different-color">r</span>em</p>
```

If you only have access to css (as mentioned in the comments), try adding gradient color to the text and place it in such a way that only 'R' gets the different color

Comment: Yeah I already know this but i can't change this on my live code.

Comment: you only have access to css?

Comment: Yes i have access only for css.

Comment: Maybe try adding gradient color to the text and place it in such a way that only 'R' gets the different color

Comment: Yeah but not getting exact result.